# JCas type used in Java code, but was not declared in the XML type descriptor

Tags: uima, dkpro-core, uimafit

I am new in DKPro Core even in UIMA and uimaFIT. I am trying to run a project but getting the error:
JCas type "`de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.discourse.pdtb.DiscourseArgument`" used in Java code,  but was not declared in the XML type descriptor

In the code, the descriptor:

```
AnalysisEngineDescription preprocessing = createEngineDescription(
                        createEngineDescription(LanguageToolSegmenter.class),
                        createEngineDescription(ParagraphAnnotator.class),
                        createEngineDescription(MateLemmatizer.class, MateLemmatizer.PARAM_LANGUAGE, "en"),
                        createEngineDescription(SnowballStemmer.class),
                        createEngineDescription(StanfordParser.class, StanfordParser.PARAM_WRITE_PENN_TREE, true),
                        createEngineDescription(StanfordSentimentAnnotator.class),
                                createEngineDescription(PDTBDiscourseAnnotator.class)
                );
```

`de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.discourse.pdtb.DiscourseArgument` is used in PDTBDiscourseAnnotator.class in th efollowing line:

```
 DiscourseArgument discourseArgument = new DiscourseArgument(jCas);
```

and the error is starting from there.

As far as I understand from the uimaFIT documentation, that using uimaFIT we don't need XML descriptor if we use  createEngineDescription(class_name), if so, then why the error says: 
`"not declared in the XML type descriptor"`.

Other classes for example:  "`SnowballStemmer.class`" use the same kind of calling like intantiate another class with jcas argument

```
Stem stemAnnot = new Stem(jcas, fs.getBegin(), fs.getEnd());
```

but error is not happening in those cases.

Any idea or clue about this error? Is my understanding correct

Answer (score 2):

This error appears when you have generated a JCas class give a given type and use it in your code but at the same time, the (J)CAS has not been initialized with a type system containing that type.

**What does it mean in practice?**

- You have some UIMA type system description XML file somewhere which defines your type `DiscourseArgument`.
- You have used JCasGen to create a JCas Java class from that type system.
- You are using uimaFIT to construct your pipeline (i.e. `createEngineDescription(...)`).
- uimaFIT automatically scans the class path for UIMA type system description XML files to use when initializing the pipeline.
- However, you have **not** made uimaFIT aware of your own type description file and therefore uimaFIT does not find it and you get the error.

**How to resolve it?**

You need to follow some conventions such that uimaFIT is able to [detect and load](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/tools.uimafit.book.html#ugr.tools.uimafit.typesystem) your custom type:

- create a file `META-INF/org.apache.uima.fit/types.txt` in a source folder (if you are using Maven, then under `src/main/resources`.
- put into it the location of your type description xml file, e.g. `classpath*:some/package/my-custom-type-description.xml`

Once you did that, uimaFIT should automatically detect your type and the error should go away.

**Why does it not happen with DKPro Core's own classes?**

Because the DKPro Core artifacts include `META-INF/org.apache.uima.fit/types.txt` files which allow uimaFIT to auto-detect the types.

Comment: After providing  [this](https://github.com/UKPLab/emnlp2017-claim-identification/blob/master/src/main/resources/desc/types/PennDiscourseTreeBankTypeSystem.xml) custom type system, which defines the DiscourseArgument and some other discourse related type, I am getting this error: 
CAS type system doesn''t match JCas Type definition for type "{0}"

Comment: What is the meaning of this error? can you give me any clue, please?

Comment: Could it be that you are somehow mixing JCas classes from DKPro Core proper with the type descriptions from the EMNLP 2017 claim identification repo or vice versa? Or do you mix different versions of DKPro Core in your project. I have just cloned https://github.com/UKPLab/emnlp2017-claim-identification.git and built it locally - builds ok for me.

Comment: Could you please try to build this locally? Then may be it will be more clear what is the problem.

Comment: Where does that project originally come from. Is there a public repository for it?

Comment: There is no public repository for. I got it for research purpose. So I think I should delete this.

Comment: While I was installing this, some of the jar file maven could not download it. 
These are: 
`de.tudarmstadt.ukp.experiments.CaS:dl:0.0.1.0`

`de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordsentiment-gpl:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordsentiment-gpl:1.6.1`

`de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.discourse.pdtbparser:de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.discourse.pdtbparser:1.7.0`

So, I downloaded some java files that are used in the code and supposed to be contained in those above-mentioned jars.
Do you think those jars contains some type systems, that I am missing here?
Why maven is failing to download those?

Comment: I'd suggest you ask the person from whom you got the code how to get it to run. These artifacts are not part of the official DKPro Core.